# Connecting hifi sterio speakers to my pc

Tags: speakers

My computer speakers have finally packed up( 12 Years old...Is it possible to utilise and connect to pc my large sterio speakers from hifi system( No longer used )  It seems a shame to discard these big speakers.

Answer (score 1):

It seems quite likely (since you provided no useful details) that your "stereo speakers" are NOT "powered" (have their own internal power amplifier).  So, to take the audio out of your computer, you need an audio power amplifier to generate a signal strong enough to drive typical stereo speakers.  There are many small and inexpensive "Class D" and "Class T" audio power amplifiers available that would do a great job at a very low price.

Comment: This kind of thing: https://www.amazon.co.uk/LEPY-LP-2024A-Plus-Amplifier/dp/B00QYAOYKW